# Facebook like slide menu below toolbar in android?

Tags: android, menu

I have created facebook like slide menu by following this tutorial:
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Facebook-Style-Slide-Menu-In-Android

Now the issue is i want to open menu below toolbar.How it can be done?

Comment: Use NavigationView. This method is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You should move DrawerLayout as top parent and move Toolbar out of DrawerLayout content container. In short this looks like:

```
    RelativeLayout
 ----Toolbar
 ----DrawerLayout
     ---ContentView
     ---DrawerList
```

Try this. For more help follow [this](http://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial) link, and change layout accordingly.